# Customise/scale axis tick marks for 4 plots independent of each other in facet_wrap

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have created this plot:-

[image: 1]

using this code:-

```
ggplot(data = gdt, aes(x = area)) + 
geom_histogram(bins = 10, colour = "black", fill = "grey50") +
facet_wrap( ~ fires, scales = "free") +
labs(x = "Area of Burnt Land (ha)", y = "Fires") +
ggtitle("Count of Destructive Fires in Portugal (2007)")
```

I want to change the interval occurrence or the location of the tick marks individually for each sub plot. In other words, I am trying to achieve a placement of one tick/grid-line at each point the bars meet. I have tried using scale_continuous and scale_x_discrete to no effect. If I set the marks to suit one of the sub plots, it negatively affects the others. Is there a way to do this??

Comment: don't know if `ggplot::facet_x` can do this. You can however build a similar display with 4 individual charts via `cowplot::plot_grid`

Comment: You ask for a specific tick placement but I see no specifics????

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to your question:

1. "achieve a placement of one tick/grid-line at each point the bars meet", and
2. plot 4 sub-plots.

The main idea is to use a combination of the `binwidth` and `boundary` arguments in `geom_histogram`, together with `scale_x_continuous`, to get the gridlines aligned with the bars; then use `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package to arrange the plots on the same page.

Some fake data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
d <- data.frame(x = c(runif(100, 0, 1),
                      runif(500, 1, 10),
                      runif(100, 10, 50),
                      runif(100, 50, 1500)))
cuts <- c(0, 1, 10, 50, 1500)
d$type <- cut(d$x, cuts)
```

Create a list of `ggplot`s, with each `ggplot` representing a subset of the data:

```
g <- lapply(split(d, d$type), function(dd) {
    i <- as.numeric(dd$type)[1]
    bw <- (cuts[i + 1] - cuts[i]) / 10
    ggplot(dd, aes(x = x)) +      
      geom_histogram(bins = 10, colour = "black", fill = "grey50",
                     binwidth = bw, boundary = cuts[i]) +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(cuts[i], cuts[i + 1], bw)) + 
      labs(y = "", x = "") +
      facet_wrap(~ type, scales = "free") # just to create panel
})
```

Arrange the subplots on a page, and add labels:

```
params <- list(top = "Count of Destructive Fires in Portugal (2007)",
               left = "Fires",
               bottom = "Area of Burnt Land (ha)")
do.call(grid.arrange, c(g, params))
```

[image]